# Product Search using geolocation of shops

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to search for product using nearby shops
Here is my code

```
Shop::selectRaw(" id  ,
                     ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                       cos( radians( lat ) )
                       * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?)
                       ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                       sin( radians( lat ) ) )
                     ) AS distance", [$latitude, $longitude, $latitude])
            ->having("distance", "<", $radius)
            ->orderBy("distance",'asc')->products()->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%')->get();
```

But I am getting this error message:

> "message": "Call to undefined method
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::products()"

Note: The Relationship between shop and product is working in my other functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am really confused, why are you using `products()` after `orderBy` and all the other clauses ?

If you are trying to get `products` from a shop, you do not have to do `products()`, you have to use `Product::....`, but if you want to get shops related to `products` you have to use `whereHas('products', ....)`, read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

Your code should be like this:

```php
$shops = Shop::selectRaw(
        "id, (6371 * acos(
            cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians(?)) + sin(radians(?)) * sin(radians(lat))
        )) AS distance", 
        [$latitude, $longitude, $latitude])
    ->having("distance", "<", $radius)
    ->orderBy("distance",'asc')
    ->whereHas('products', function ($query) use ($keyword) {
        return $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%');
    })
    ->with('products')
    ->get();
```

That code will give you shops, you can then do `$shops->products`.

But if you want directly to get the `products` you have to use the `Product` model:

```php
$products = Product::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%')
    ->whereHas('shops', function ($query) use ($latitude, $longitude, $latitude, $radius) {
        return $query->selectRaw(
            "id, (6371 * acos(
                cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians(?)) + sin(radians(?)) * sin(radians(lat))
            )) AS distance", 
            [$latitude, $longitude, $latitude]
        )
        ->having("distance", "<", $radius)
        ->orderBy("distance",'asc');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Awesome ! Could you mark my answer as correct ?